# Read an array of structs in C#

Tags: c#

I've seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384/read-binary-file-into-a-struct-c/534819#534819) , and also googling for "marshal" several ways to convert a byte array to a struct.

But what I'm looking for is if there is a way to read an array of structs from a file (ok, whatever memory input) in one step?

I mean, load an array of structs from file normally takes more CPU time (a read per field using a BinaryReader) than IO time. Is there any workaround?

I'm trying to load about 400K structs from a file as fast as possible.

Thanks

pablo

Comment: Are you reading them from one big file or 400k small files? If you have all in one file reading should be quite fast I think

Answer (score 1):

Following URL may be of interest to you.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/fastbinaryfileinput.aspx

Or otherwise I think of pseudo code like the following:

readbinarydata in a single shot and convert back to structure..

```
public struct YourStruct
{ 
    public int First;
    public long Second;
    public double Third;
}

static unsafe byte[] YourStructToBytes( YourStruct s[], int arrayLen )
{
    byte[] arr = new byte[ sizeof(YourStruct) * arrayLen ];
    fixed( byte* parr = arr )
    { 
        * ( (YourStruct * )parr) = s; 
    }
    return arr;
}

static unsafe YourStruct[] BytesToYourStruct( byte[] arr, int arrayLen )
{
    if( arr.Length < (sizeof(YourStruct)*arrayLen) )
        throw new ArgumentException();
    YourStruct s[];
    fixed( byte* parr = arr )
    { 
        s = * ((YourStruct * )parr); 
    }
    return s;
}
```

Now you can read bytearray from the file in a single shot and convert back to strucure using BytesToYourStruct

Hope you can implement this idea and check...

Comment: Unfortunately they do it "one by one" here, which is exactly what I want to avoid

Comment: The fixed solution seems to be what I was looking for! thanks!

Comment: Didn't compile on Mono: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'YourStruct[]' to YourStruct"

Answer (score 0):

I found a potential solution at this site -
http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/32846931/writingreading-an-array.aspx

It says basically to use Binary Formatter like this:

FileStream fs = new FileStream("DataFile.dat", FileMode.Create);
BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
formatter.Serialize(fs, somestruct);

I also found two questions from this site - [Reading a C/C++ data structure in C# from a byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871/reading-a-c-c-data-structure-in-c-from-a-byte-array)
and
[How to marshal an array of structs - (.Net/C# => C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31854/how-to-marshal-an-array-of-structs-net-c-c)

I haven't done this before, being a C# .NET beginner myself. I hope this solution helps.

Comment: Thanks, but "Serialize" is slow compared to direct memory access, and the other links use "PtrToStructure" to copy "one by one" which is exactly what I want to avoid.

Comment: Sorry pablo, I had computer trouble yesterday. So I couldn't follow up. I am not sure how to achieve what you want. All the best with that.

Comment: I hope you find out. If you do, please post an answer here. Thanks.