# Marshaling C arrays in C#

Tags: c#, .net, c, dll, marshalling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Marshaling c structures in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9188523/marshaling-c-structures-in-c-sharp)

## Actual C structures:

```
typedef struct procedure
{
  char code[8];
}procedure;

typedef struct p45_cldxed24
{
  procedure p45_cldxed[8];
}p45_cldxed24;
```

What would be the equivalent C# structure for p45_cldxed24?  Specifically, how would you marshal the array?

[check this out once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9188523/marshaling-c-structures-in-c-sharp)

### Is this correct?

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
struct p45_cldxed24
{
    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType=UnmanagedType.Struct,SizeConst = 8,SizeParamIndex=0)]
    procedure[] p45_cldxed;
}
```

Comment: @Cody Gray 
its not duplicate, i only asked that question.

Comment: @CodyGray I asked Raghuveer to start a new question.  The question that you referenced was focused on strings.

Comment: @Zenexer: Same question.

Comment: Well, I thought they were different enough in context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the code would be as follows:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
struct p45_cldxed24
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 8)]
    procedure[] p45_cldxed;
}
```

The key here is that `MarshalAs` attribute.

Comment: Is this correct?
-

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    struct p45_cldxed24
    {
        [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType=UnmanagedType.Struct,SizeConst = 8,SizeParamIndex=0)]
        procedure[] p45_cldxed;
    }

Comment: No, as @Zenexer said in his answer you want ByValArray - you can read about the different values here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.unmanagedtype.aspx. In particular "You can only use this UnmanagedType on an array that appear as fields in a structure"