# Converting a C struct to C#?

Tags: c#, interop, marshalling, handle

I have an API written in C++ and am attempting to use this with interop in C# Windows forms.
I am having difficulty defining the equivalent C# struct.
Here is the C++ struct:

```
typedef struct
{
    char SerNo[LENGTH];
    HANDLE dev;
} myDevice;
```

## Edit:

Thanks to the comments the first item is solved.
Here is the current C# status:

```
    public unsafe struct sdrplay_api_DeviceT
    {
        [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 64)]
        string SerNo;

        public IntPtr dev;
    }
```

However nothing I try get's the  HANDLE.  So I guess at this time, I will expand on the code further:

In the original C++ code, there is a function as follows:

*GetDevices(myDevice *devs);*

and in the C# code I have done this:

```
 public unsafe static extern GetDevices([In, Out] myDevice[] devs);
```

Now the code I use is as follows:

```
myDevice[] devs = new myDevice[6];

var error = GetDevices(devs);
```

If I look at devs in Visual Studio I see the SerNo (devs[0].SerNo) correctly but the "handle is always 0;

I tried IntPtr, byte, but I am at a loss.
Thanks, Tom

Comment: This is C code not C++ code.

Comment: What's different about those dozens that you could do them all, but not this one?

Comment: The difficulty is how do you define these two items in C#?  All the others were either unsigned char (becomes byte) or double etc. These two I have not found the C# equivalent

Comment: For marshalling the `char SerNo[LENGTH]` array see [Marshal C++ struct array into C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/188299/3744182).  You may also need [Marshaling c structures in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9188760/3744182).

Comment: `HANDLE` could be anything. Look up the `typedef` or `#define`.

Comment: `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=LENGTH)] string SerNo` and `IntPtr dev`?

Comment: @Tom the `HANDLE` is probably another `struct` or a Macro, without knowing its definition, we cannot say anything regarding that.

Comment: @n314159 Why would this not be valid C++ code?

Comment: @GSerg It is valid C++ code, but the usage of the `typedef` before the `struct` suggests that is really C code (that is just in that subset of C code that is supported by C++) since for C the `typedef` is needed to not always have to write `struct myDevice` when using it while in C++ this also given for `struct myDevice {...};` as definition.

Comment: `HANDLE` is presumably `typedef PVOID HANDLE;` as defined in `WinNT.h`, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types

Comment: @GSerg If that code is standard conforming C++ depends on whether `LENGTH` is a compile-time constant expression or not.

Comment: Could be char[], byte[] or string, decorated with [MarshalAs] to make it a ByValArray or ByValTStr.  Which one you need depends on the C code, whether it stores a 0-terminated C string in the field and what kind of encoding it assumes.  Start with byte[] if you have no idea, the debugger can give you some insight.

Comment: @dbc The link you sent worked for the first entry! This in particular:             [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 64)]
            public string SerNo;